# SQL Server equivalent of mysql_data_seek

Tags: php, sql-server

I am working on a web application which returns large tables of statistics from a database, using SQL Server (not my call). In my code I have several functions with while loops of the type :

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

However, since the tables are so large I would like to make as few calls to the database as possible to minimize loading time. That means I would like to somehow reset the internal pointer of the database statement after these while-loops. My experiece with SQL Server is limited, to say the least, and googling suggest that in MySQL I should be able to use the mysql_data_seek-function. Is there an equivalent in SQL Server? Is it even possible?

Comment: I found an answer to a similar problem here [link](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/thread/d22883bd-00bb-4fa5-bc33-83da68985ff4). Seems like there is no simple fix to this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlsrv_fetch($stmt,SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST);
```

in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php